# Where do I create, or add to, a .div to allow scroll with overflow? - Shopify

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I have a vertical image gallery with several pictures and to the right, a full-size render of whichever image is selected at the time. What I'm trying to achieve is to define the height of the .div (within which are the full-size and thumbnail images) so that I can use the cut-off height (that would align with the bottom margin of the full-size render, though its size is responsive to page size, excepting mobile-widths and below) as means to set the image gallery's overflow to "scroll" instead of having it trail so far down the page.

[See an example of the product page template here.](https://yourthreads.co/products/sheer-tan)

The site is mostly built using a discontinued Shopify theme, Flow by WeTheme, however I've investigated and fixed its issues in the past with some experience in front end languages, so if you have any clues as to what direction I could take, I'd really appreciate it! Thank you!

[CSS code details 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyToA.png)

[CSS code details 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gs8BR.png)

[CSS code details 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28na3.png)

[Liquid code details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oAsq.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code and actually include the code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `height` and `overflow` to achieve such a behaviour.

```css
#right 
{
  float: left;
}

#left 
{
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#left > img 
{
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "wrapper">
<div id = "left">
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
</div>
<div id = "right">
<image src = "https://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
</div>
</div>
```